# Smarty Not Generating Javascript on all Files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, smarty

I have a standard PHP/Smarty Website. There is a home base with index.php, a templates folder with the .tpl Files. I have a header.tpl, footer.tpl, index.tpl and subpage.tpl.

The index.tpl and subpage.tpl both include the header.tpl. I know they are both have the header.tpl included correctly because css is the same on both pages. In the head tag on the header.tpl I have a jQuery autocomplete script. If I have the text box on the index.tpl the autocomplete works.

If I place the same input text box code on the subpage The Autocomplete does not work. I force compile smarty, removed all cache and can't seem to figure out why? Any Ideas?

My Header .tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

... my css

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/onchange.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Part_Number").autocomplete("autocomplete/parts.php", {
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

my index.tpl and subpage.tpl

```
 {include file="header.tpl" page="Home"}
 <input type="text" id="Part_Number" name="Part_Number"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can be different in your 2 pages are the URI you are calling:
`$("#Part_Number").autocomplete("autocomplete/parts.php", {`
try to put an absolute path like this:
`$("#Part_Number").autocomplete("http://www.example.com/autocomplete/parts.php", {`

Comment: @ClemSndr That Didn't work, It still only works on the index.tpl page and not the subpage.tpl

Comment: Can you look in the inspector if the script is correctly loaded and if there is any error in the javascript console ?

Comment: @ClemSndr Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) is the Error Message. There are a correct amount of Brackets I believe

Comment: try to put your js code between a {literal}{/literal} tag just to be sure that it's not a problem of bad interpretation of the brackets.